# How to apply style to Chrome without affecting Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to apply a style for chrome to fix a bug. I'm able to get it working, but when I check it in Edge I get now edge looks off. How can I apply my style to just Chrome (I'm using version 60), without affecting any other browsers?

```
@media (min-width: 860px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    table.content tbody tr td { min-width: 90px; }
}

@media (min-width: 711px) and (max-width: 860px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    table.content tbody tr td { min-width: 60px; }
}
```

Comment: `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { }` can be used for WebKit browsers(this will affect Safari as well)

Comment: Do you care about affecting Safari? Also Chrome on Windows and Chrome on Mac (and iOS) have different implementations and sometimes this kind of queries don't work for both. Also sometimes bug are only relevant for Windows or Mac.

Comment: @APAD1 When I try `@media screen and (min-width: 860px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)` edge is still being affected.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Right now, I'm not concerned with Macs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To target specific browser you can use `@supports` and combine supported and/or unsupported CSS properties by particular browser. Also you can exclude other browsers this way.

If you care only about Chrome on Windows, you should know that it doesn't support `hyphens: auto` even with `-webkit` prefix (but Chrome for Mac and Android supports `-webkit-hyphens: auto`) so to target Chrome for Windows with media query use

```
@supports not ((-webkit-hyphens: auto) or (-ms-hyphens: auto) or (hyphens: auto)) {
/* Your styles here */
}
```

Example

```css
@supports not ((-webkit-hyphens: auto) or (-ms-hyphens: auto) or (hyphens: auto)) {
  * {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
This is red, but only in Chrome for Windows
```

Comment: Can this be combined with the width constraints?

Comment: @AntarrByrd You mean with nested `@media` query? Yes, Chrome seems to support this.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov This is red for me, too, Chrome/Debian ;) But I like your idea, take my upvote

Comment: @SVSchmidt This is OK, `-webkit-hyphens: auto` are supported by Chrome only for Mac and Android, so I am honest. I didn't take Linux into account when writing answer. Thanks for upvote.